# Passing and existing project to androidx gives me Could not resolve com.google.android:support-v4:r11

Tags: java, android, gradle, androidx

I am changing my code to androidx but while I tried gradle sync gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':Debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android:support-v4:r11.
Show Details
Affected Modules: AppName


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':DebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android:support-v4:r11.
Show Details
Affected Modules: AppName


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':DebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android:support-v4:r11.
Show Details
Affected Modules: AppName
```

Things I have tried:
1:Go to File->Other Settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Uncheck Offline work option.
Offline option was unchecked.

2. Invalidate your cache and restart. Nothing happens with this, same error appears.
3. Clean project / Rebuild project / Sync project with gradle files / restart android studio. Same error appears.

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {

        myapp {
            minSdkVersion 20
            applicationId 'be.myapp
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 130
            versionName '2.5.3'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myapp
            manifestPlaceholders = [ROTATION_PREF: "unspecified"]
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
    }

}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
        implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    annotationProcessor 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.amber:amber-oauth2-client:0.22-incubating'
    implementation 'org.apache.amber:amber-oauth2-common:0.22-incubating'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2'
}
```

**SOLUTION:** It was a libraries incompatibilities. 
Changing org.parceler:parceler implementation to a new version and checking all libraries have the last version the error is gone

Comment: where I have to add this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this lines, add

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

and check what other artefacts set correctly: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: I tried changing implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' to implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01' but the same issue is showing. Also check the web and make all steps

Comment: I don't see com.google.android:support-v4:r11 in your Gradle file. Where Android studio refference this error? Try to "find in path" with "com.google.android:support"

Comment: I have search in find in path in all project and nothing to show appears. It's so strange

Comment: try to press (Top menu) Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX